# How to add missing Months in Django Python List of Dictionary

Tags: python, django

<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=), 'total': 1}, {'month': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=), 'total': 1}]>

How to add Missing Month of May (5) in which 'total' is equal to Zero in above?

Comment: May be if you share your models and query that will help.

Comment: class Subjectcalculation(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve, but there is actually no easy way. You will have to add it after evaluating the queryset in your own code. Try iterating over each month you want to be included, checking whether there is an entry for it and add if there isn't